# Change tableviewcell height dynamically when tap

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table view filled by some custom table view cells, in every cell there is a `UILabel` whose original `numberOFLines` is 5. The contents of this `UILabel` could be more than 5 lines so if I set `numberOFLines` to 0, this `UILabel` could expand to 10 lines or even more so when I set `numberOFLines` to 0, cell height should be bigger.

Suppose that at first when `numberOfLines` is 5, height of one cell is 200. When I tap this label, `numberOfLines` is set to 0, this label tries to display all content and there should be 10 lines of text, height of this cell should be 250 so it can show all contents properly. And when I tap it again, `numberOfLines` should go back to 5 and cell height should go back to 200.

So I add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to this label and when tapped, a method is called to reset `numberOfLines`:

```
- (void)mainContentLabelTapped {
    NSLog(@"main content label tapped");
    (self.mainContentLabel.numberOfLines == 0) ?
            [self.mainContentLabel setNumberOfLines:5]:
            [self.mainContentLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
}
```

The problem is that when I tap `mainContentLable`, this label itself would expand to more lines or shrink back to 5 lines but cell height remain unchanged until I scroll this cell out of screen and scroll it back again so its height could be recalculated.

So how to change cell height when I click that label?

There are tons of questions in stackoverflow about dynamic height of table view cell but all solutions are to send message to tableview such as `begin/endUpdate` or `reloadData`. In my question tap gesture is token care in `.m` file of my own cell so I can't find a way to send those messages to table view and ask it recalculate cell height.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You must reload UITableView, and change height of either particular cell by reloading.

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
    }

    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if ([indexPath compare:selectedIndexPath] == NSOrderedSame) {
            return 80;
        }
        return 40;
    }
```

By this, the selected Row height will be more than others.

Thanks

Happy Coding!